# How can I add bounty to my question?

Tags: support, bounty

There isn't add bounty button "below the comment area of the question" as the FAQ suggested. My reputation is only 59, and I am using Chrome/ff - neither work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must have 75 reputation to offer a bounty. More information can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties).

Comment: And *even more* information can be found here: [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065)